# How to postMessage in JS to specific script in iframe in another domain

Tags: javascript, html, message

I have iframe B in iframe A like this:

```
<iframe id="receiver">
 <script>
  top.getElementById("sender").addEventListener('message' receiveMessage, false);
  function receiveMesage(evt)
  {
   do something
  }
 </script>
 <iframe id="sender" src="SenderHtml">
</iframe>
```

And in SenderHtml I have:

```
 <script>
    top.postMessage("data, '*');

 </script>
```

First, I can't seems to make it work correctly. 
But more importantly, iframe "receiver" can be in a page with much more data, how can I ensure that no one else will catch the data sent to it? I have no control over the rest of the data in its page. Can I tell the script in SenderHtml to send only to the "reciever" frame by id?
One other aspect is that the 2 pages are in different domains.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer in the end.
The issue is that there is code inside the iframe, it is a mistake.
I added another redirection and it solved the issue (all are in the body of the corresponding html file):

OuterFrame.html:

```
<iframe id="receiver" src="Listener.html">
```

Listener.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       window.addEventListener('message', receiveMessage, false);
       function receiveMessage(evt) 
       {
           alert("got message: " + evt.data);
       }

</script>
<iframe id="sender" src="Sender.html"></iframe>
```

Sender.Html:

```
<script>
  parent.postMessage("data, '*');
</script>
```